# add an extra column while select from two tables

Tags: mysql, jdbc

i have two tables with me, web and mail. currently i am using this query to fetch data from both tables.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("(select * from web where name='abc') union (select * from mail where name='abc')");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){      
bw.write(rs3.getString("name")+"~"+rs3.getString("age")+"~"+rs3.getString("profession");
bw.newLine();
}
```

The output is something like this.

```
+------+------+------------+
| name | age  | profession |
+------+------+------------+
| abc  |   20 | doctor     |
| abc  |   20 | engineer   |
+------+------+------------+
```

and in the file its like this

```
abc~20~doctor
abc~20~engineer
```

but how can i add an extra column in the result set which will give me data in this format

```
abc~20~doctor~web
abc~20~engineer~mail
```

Comment: [Check this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836972/manually-add-data-to-a-java-resultset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * , 'web' as source from web where name='abc' union
select *, 'mail' as source from mail where name ='abc'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try this 

select * , 'web' as tablename from web where name='abc' union
select * ,'mail' as table namefrom mail where name='abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("(select name,age,profession ,'web' AS ExtraColumnfrom from web where name='abc') union (select name,age,profession ,'mail' AS ExtraColumnfrom mail where name='abc')");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){      
bw.write(rs3.getString("name")+"~"+rs3.getString("age")+"~"+rs3.getString("profession")+"~"+rs3.getString("ExtraColumnfrom ");
bw.newLine();
}
```