# java app- show only non-empty boxes/fields from mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu1MR.png

The problem is, `setModel()` shows everything.
Is there a way to show only non-empty fields?

### Edit

I have this to get the table to the java app:

```
public void showExports(){  
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(getResultSet("select * from t1")));
}
```

But as you can see in the picture, in last column are many empty fields before last date input.

Can I show only the nonempty ones?

Comment: `setModel() `?? For what?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please read the guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DevilsHnd  i wrote something more about it :)

Comment: [See this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836972/manually-add-data-to-a-java-resultset).

Comment: As per SO guidelines, all code, data, and error messages must be entered as text, not images. Text in images can be difficult to read, especially on mobile devices. Also, volunteers need the ability to copy-paste into their editors, or into search engines (esp error messages), both for efficiency reasons, & to avoid introducing typos of their own. Finally, grammar and spelling are very important for readability, clarity, and understanding. Quality of SO, and its value to the community rely on the quality of every post - be it a question, or an answer. Please `edit` to avoid the Q being closed.

Comment: capitalization, grammar, inline code formatting

Comment: Welcome to SO. A little guidance on asking questions: 1) Your second question entirely unclear. 2) As per SO guidelines, generally only 1 question should be in any post. Generally a second question warrants a new post. Due to the format of SO,  adding & upvoting answers would breakdown if they could apply to a fraction of a post's questions. Searching questions/answers also break down if questions are buried as a secondary questions within a post. Please review the main topics under [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking additional questions, and `edit` this one accordingly.

Comment: typo, remove second question (which was added later) to avoid closure of *this* question: 1) it is entirely unclear (so would need to be closed, or edited by OP) 2) violates 1 Question / post policy 3) The rest of the Q was editable to avoid closure.